# How do i get links from href="animals.html" in php DOM?

Tags: php, html, dom, preg-match, str-replace

My pages are www.example.com/somthing/types.html , www.example.com/somthing2/types.html  this html files has a tag`<a href="animals.html" . somthing,somthing2`are files every file contains links in types.html and files  like animals.html in the same folders.
when i get it with dom it shows only "animals.html" but i want to get "www.example.com/somthing/animals.html". how can i remove  types.html from www.example.com/somthing/types.html and put www.example.com/somthing+/animals.html.

i just need a way to remove  "types.html"  from  www.example.com/somthing/types.html.
keep the folder and remove the last part after this "/".

i dont know always last part (file name) so i need a way to remove last thing after last "/". sorry about my language problems.
`str_replace('types.html' ,'','www.example.com/somthing/types.html');`is for if i know the file name (types.html).

Comment: If you want "absolute URLs" in your doc, why don't you use `<base href="http://www.example.com/somthing/">`? Once the doc is out of context (I guess it is what you want to achieve, it will resolve the full link without any parsing/replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
preg_replace('/([^\/]*$)/', '', 'www.example.com/somthing/types.html');
```

This will replace all characters after the last `/`

Output will be `www.example.com/somthing/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this the old fashion way:

```
$url = 'www.example.com/somthing/types.html';

$divided = explode( '/', $url );
array_pop( $divided );

$new_url = implode( '/', $divided );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
$string = 'www.examle.com/somthing/types.html';
echo preg_replace('#\/[^/]*$#', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering the fast and the fastest you may consider this piece of code instead preg_replace

```
$url = explode("/",$url);
array_pop($url);
$url = implode("/",$url);
```

Again it is slighly faster so do as you please :).

Proof:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5083e02d4f171502ef1e7c87c8dd9a957ee0d8fb